# Android Studio add watch shortcut

Tags: android-studio, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any shortcut for Add Watch in android studio?
While debug windows is focused I can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>, but this is not working in code editor.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct shortcut for **Add to Watches** but you can define your own.

> 1. Go to File -> Settings -> Keymap
> 2. Expand 'Other' folder at last and find 'Add to Watches'.
> 3. Double Click / Right Click on it and select 'Add Keyboard Shortcut'.
> 4. Enter your keys and Done!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to assign a combination to your liking under preferences -> keymap -> search for "watches"?